# include ファイルを開けません。'qedit.h'というエラーへの対処

Tags: windows, visual-studio

少々古いVisual Studioのソルーションを動かそうとしたところ、次のエラーが出てしまいました。

> エラー C1083 include ファイルを開けません。'qedit.h':No such file or directory

検索したら、次のサイトがみつかりました。
http://www.independence-sys.com/weblog/item/209

それによりますと、DirectShowの開発環境の一つで、Windows SDK v6.1が必要なようですが、古すぎてダウンロードできないようです。

何とかダウンロードする方法、もしくは他の方法はないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

当該ヘッダーだけでなく、その中でインクルードされる他のヘッダーも必要になるかもしれません。さらに、多分*.libと*.dllも必要になります。
一般に、古いプロジェクトをビルドし試してみるためには、

(1)それに対応した古いSDK
(2)上記に対応しているコンパイル環境(Visual Studio の古いもの)
(3)コンパイラとビルドした結果を動作させられる古いOS

の3点セットが必要となります。ただし、(2)(3)はケースバイケースで、必須と言うわけではありませんが。
古いMSDNライブラリ(多分CD)を持っている場合はたいがいその中に入ってます。手間ですが。
残念ながら気軽に実験できるものではないので、上記の何れかが欠損している場合で、強く望まない場合はあきらめた方が良いかもしれません。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。だいぶエラーを修正したのですが、残りがいくつかというところまで来ていますので、もう少し頑張ってみます。

Answer (score 1):

`qedit.h`なら[Microsoft® Windows® Software Development Kit Update for Windows Vista™](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14477)に含まれていそうです。

---

Uncle-Keiさんが説明されていますが、私が上記回答をした経緯を説明しておきます。`qedit.h`で定義される[`ISampleGrabber`のドキュメント](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/desktop/DirectShow/isamplegrabber)を参照したところ

> To obtain Qedit.h, download the Microsoft Windows SDK Update for Windows Vista and .NET Framework 3.0. Qedit.h is not available in the Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1.

とMicrosoft社も現行Windows SDKに同梱されていないことを認識した上で、古いWindows SDKを提示していました。つまり、`qedit.h`に限っては過去のWindows SDKからコピーして利用することを暗示しています。なおリンク先は既にdead linkでした。[Windows SDK とエミュレーターのアーカイブ](https://developer.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/downloads/sdk-archive)もありますがこちらもdead linkでしたので、適当にググって見つけたリンクを提示しました。
また[大した内容ではないので書いてしまえ](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/ja-JP/2ab5c212-5824-419d-b5d9-7f5db82f57cd/qedith-missing-in-current-windows-sdk-v70?forum=windowsdirectshowdevelopment)、というフォーラムでのやり取りも見つけました。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。ダウンロードに時間がかかりますが、何とか試して見ます。